# apache redirect not encoding % in rewriterule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^attorney/harley ssh/attorneys/attorney-detail.html?ad=Jan%20S.%20Harley [NE,NC,L,R=301]
```

When I visit `attorney/harley`, I get sent to `ssh/attorneys/attorney-detail.html?ad=Jan0S.0Harley`.

How can I change my RewriteRule to include the percent signs in the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `%`'s because that's a backreference to a previous matched group in a `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteRule ^attorney/harley ssh/attorneys/attorney-detail.html?ad=Jan\%20S.\%20Harley [NE,NC,L,R=301]
```